# Como ordenar listview de acordo com uma coluna específica

Tags: vb.net, listview, visual-basic-6

Tenho uma listview que mostra mais ou menos o seguinte:

```
ID    NOME    IDADE
0     Luis     19
1     Julio    33
2     Marcio   27
```

O problema é que quando o ID chega em 10, a listview começa a colocar o 11, 12, 13... antes do 2, ficando algo tipo:

```
ID    NOME     IDADE
0     Luis      19
1     Julio     33
11    Claudio   33
12    Felipe    33
2     Marcio    27
```

Queria saber como corrigir isso, fazendo com que o 11, 12, 13... venha depois do 10, e etc.

Descobri recentemente que o problema está no código que lê os arquivos(as informações são tiradas de arquivos XML)

```
Dim DirDiretorio As DirectoryInfo = New DirectoryInfo(pedidosPath)
Dim oFileInfoCollection() As FileInfo
Dim oFileInfo As FileInfo
Dim i As Integer
oFileInfoCollection = DirDiretorio.GetFiles()
For i = 0 To oFileInfoCollection.Length() - 1
    oFileInfo = oFileInfoCollection.GetValue(i)
    'Pega os dados do arquivo
Next
```

Com uma MessageBox descobri que ele pega o 10, 11, 12, ... antes do 2. Algum código alternativo?

Comment: Não entendo muito de vb, mas você está tratando essa coluna como inteiro(se é que é assim que o vb enxerga tipos)? Já vi problemas parecidos em outras linguagem e, no fim, o problema era a forma de tratamento do tipo.

Comment: Na vedade, essa lista é muito maior, são 7 subitens, esse exemplo que eu coloquei foi bem tosco.
O programa adiciona os valores a partir de arquivos XML, ou seja, cada item (ID, NOME, IDADE) está dentro de um XML. Não entendi muito bem sua pergunta, mas eu adiciono o item inteiro a partir de um arquivo só.

Comment: Acho que fui meio confuso, te perguntei se você trata o tipo da coluna id como `int`(numeros inteiros). Em outras linguagens, esse problema era causado porque a ordenação da coluna ficava errada porque o programa lia como string.

Comment: Ah sim, entendi. ela ta como String, ja que adiciono todos os valores de todas as colunas ao mesmo tempo. 
`lstPedidos.Items.Add(New ListViewItem(New String() {"", id, nome, telefone,...}))`

Comment: Seria interessante você adicionar na perguntacomo você popula o listview com os dados. Aparentemente é um problema com tipos de dados, como eu havia dito.

Comment: Obrigado desde já!!

Answer (score -1):

Basta você usar a propriedade *ListViewItemSorter* da ListView, para ordenar por uma coluna especifica. No exemplo abaixo estou ordenando pela primeira coluna.

```
Dim ListView1 As New ListView
Dim lvwColumnSorter As ListViewColumnSorter

lvwColumnSorter = New ListViewColumnSorter()

lvwColumnSorter.SortColumn = ListView1.Columns(0).Index
lvwColumnSorter.Order = SortOrder.Ascending

ListView1.ListViewItemSorter = lvwColumnSorter

ListView1.Sort()
```

nos links abaixo há mais informações sobre ordenação de colunas em ListView.

https://support.microsoft.com/pt-br/kb/319399

https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.listview.listviewitemsorter(v=vs.110).aspx